# Custom edges with cytoscape.js?

Tags: customization, cytoscape.js

Is there a way to make custom edges with cytoscape? Can't find any info rather then a few in-bult edge types that doesn't cover my case (like taxi, bezier etc).

Is there any API in cytoscape that I can hook into to alter the edges?
Or maybe someone experienced with cytoscape could suggest a good starting point?

Comment: by using `line-style` and `line-dash-pattern` you can illustrate some of them. Showing double lines and others seems hard

Comment: @canbax I was able to draw the zigzags with custom renderer however I have a problem setting it up correctly. Maybe you could suggestions anything, I outlined the details in my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69662864/custom-renderer-issue-with-cytoscape-js

Comment: hm. are you changing the source codes of cytoscape.js?

Comment: @canbax - changing the source code is something I want to avoid actually. Seems like extensions is a way to go, but there is a slight problem in registering my custom renderer extension which I've described in the link above. I'd appreciate if you could have a look at it.

Comment: what is canvas rendered I don't know.

Comment: @canbax, never mind man! I guess I'll have to ask that stuff on github. Thanks for your time reading through my question.